# We are epic, we are everywhere

Tags: riddle, knowledge, music

**Part 1**

> We are epic, we are everywhere.
>   We hide in shadows, we give you
>   nightmares.
>
> We are your nemesis, we are a dynasty.
>   We cause diseases beyond
>   imagination or dream.
>
> We are drones we are drums.
>
> We are darkness and power,
>   We are the roman emperor.
>
> We are legend, we are ashes.
>   We are public at long last.

**Part 2**

> We are epic, we are everywhere,
>   We have our classics, it's only fair.
>
> We are invincible, it's no illusion,
>      We are the devil and the demon.
>
> We shout our battlecry, hear our legacy.
>
> We are the horror, the sky is our world.
>      We are as fast as sound as we fly.
>
> We climb the volcano, witness our miracle,
>   We are the sun, we are the archangel.

*We are the same, Who are we?*

**Hint**

> Most nouns are all related, Part 1 and 2 fit chronogically, a couple of stanzas are metaphors but not a lot of them. Either way to figure out the puzzle you have to find what links all of them. Also, you've very most likely encountered 'we' before without knowing. And check the tags.

Comment: Both parts correspond to the same thing? Or does your riddle contain 2 distinct questions?

Comment: both parts correspond to the same thing

Comment: I think I know the answer, hello hello!

Comment: We are LEGION!!!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are

> Songs/albums by the recording group [Two Steps from Hell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two_Steps_from_Hell)

We are epic, we are everywhere
We hide in shadows, we give you nightmares.

> This group has recorded tracks for a large number of motion pictures and other soundtracks
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomas_Bergersen_discography#Shadows_and_Nightmares

We are your nemesis, we are a dynasty.
We cause diseases beyond imagination or dream.

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomas_Bergersen_discography#Nemesis
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomas_Bergersen_discography#Dynasty
>
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomas_Bergersen_discography#Pathogen
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomas_Bergersen_discography#Dreams_.26_Imaginations

We are drones we are drums.

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomas_Bergersen_discography#All_Drones_Go_to_Hell
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomas_Bergersen_discography#All_Drums_Go_To_Hell

We are darkness and power,
We are the roman emperor.

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomas_Bergersen_discography#Power_of_Darkness
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomas_Bergersen_discography#Nero

We are legend, we are ashes.
We are public at long last.

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomas_Bergersen_discography#Ashes
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomas_Bergersen_discography#Legend
>
> He has been a composer since the 80's but only has public albums since 2010.

**Part 2** 
We are epic, we are everywhere,
We have our classics, it's only fair.

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomas_Bergersen_discography#Classics_Volume_One
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomas_Bergersen_discography#Classics_Volume_Two

We are invincible, it's no illusion,
We are the devil and the demon.

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomas_Bergersen_discography#Invincible
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomas_Bergersen_discography#Illusions
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomas_Bergersen_discography#The_Devil_Wears_Nada

We shout our battlecry, hear our legacy.

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomas_Bergersen_discography#Battlecry
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomas_Bergersen_discography#Legend From the OP, there is a CD called *Legacy* that was a release in Japan.

We are the horror, the sky is our world.
We are as fast as sound as we fly.

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomas_Bergersen_discography#SkyWorld

We climb the volcano, witness our miracle,
We are the sun, we are the archangel.

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomas_Bergersen_discography#Colin_Frake_on_Fire_Mountain
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomas_Bergersen_discography#Miracles
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomas_Bergersen_discography#Archangel
> From the OP, there is also an album titled Sun

Comment: Nice! there's also the album Legacy(2015 - Japan) and the album Sun(2014) (and another edition of Sun is set to release soon) - The answer I was expecting is the collaborative group though as many of those albums have as many songs written by someone else too. - Edit and I'll set as correct answer :)  **Also all the titles in part 2 are the public albums

Comment: I think I got all of that in there now ;)

Comment: Fun fact, most western major events normally have a song or two from them in the openings or background. (like the Vancouver and London Olympics - the Superbowl - or not that long ago, press conferences at E3 - without mentioning the huge amounts of trailer music they've done for both movies and games)

Answer (score 4):

Part 1 sounds like

> vampires.

*We are epic, we are everywhere.*

> Vampires are found in epic fantasy, and everywhere in horror novels.

*We hide in shadows, we give you nightmares.*

> This bit is obvious.

*We are your nemesis, we are a dynasty.*

> Vampires are the nemesis of humanity. "Dynasty" could refer to various fictional families of vampires, most notably the Cullen family of the *Twilight* series.

*We cause diseases beyond imagination or dream.*

> "Diseases" as a metaphor for blood loss and death?

*We are drones we are drums.*

> Not sure about this line.

*We are darkness and power,*

> Classic vampire boast.

*We are the roman emperor.*

> Sidorio, a vampire in the *Vampirates* series, encountered Julius Caesar while still a mortal, and used Caesar as a pseudonym on at least one occasion.

*We are legend, we are ashes.*

> Vampires are legendary. Put one into sunlight and it gets burnt to ashes.

*We are public at long last.*

> With the onset of "vampire fiction", vampires are suddenly very much in the public eye.

Comment: It's a good try but not the answer. Check the tags : )  they can help.